# How do i fix the NextPageToken not working in AWS code?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a script that is trying to get a lot of data and the part of the code that uses next page token is only giving me partial data with no error message, how do i fix the nextpagetoken part to give me all results? im asking it to give me Jan-Dec data but it's only giving me Jan-April.

```
results = []

token = None
while True:
    if token:
        kwargs = {'NextPageToken': token}
    else:
        kwargs = {}
    data = cd.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod={'Start': '2020-01-01', 'End':  
'2020-12-10'}, Granularity='DAILY', Metrics=['AmortizedCost'],
                                GroupBy=[{'Type': 'DIMENSION', 'Key': 
'LINKED_ACCOUNT'}]} ,{'Dimensions': {'Key': 'LINKED_ACCOUNT','Values': 
['123948500267568']}}]}, **kwargs)
    for info in data['ResultsByTime']:
       for group in info['Groups']:
            print(group['Keys'][0], info['TimePeriod']['Start'], 
group['Metrics']['AmortizedCost']['Amount'])#, group['Keys'][1])
    token = data.get('NextPageToken')
    if not token:
        break
```

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Any error messages? Where does the error occur exactly? What is the context of this code?

Comment: No error messages, but when i ask for data from Jan-Dec it only gives me from Jan-April. This is a script that pulls costs. There seems to be an issue with the nextpagetoken

Comment: Just to debug it... If you change the start date to May, does it return any data?

Comment: yes it does, it will give me data if i change the dates to 3 months at a time